# Highcharts: How to give a different color to each category in barcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

As the question states. I'm trying to give a different color to each category in barcharts. It can be easily done in linecharts where we can pass each series as an object. But I haven't been able to do this on barcharts. Please see the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af2PB.png) to get more clarity. 
Also, see [demo code](https://jsfiddle.net/mehraG/5cyL3x1m/2/) how I'm trying to achieve it. It looks something like below.

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Nominal Bonds', 'Inflation', 'Equity'],
},
series: [
    {
      data: [{ name:'Nominal Bonds 1',y:5 }, { name:'Nominal Bonds 2',y:23}]
    },

    {
     data: [{ name:'Inflation 1',y:15 }, { name:'Inflation 2',y:12}, { name:'Inflation 3',y:22}]
    },

    {
    data: [{ name:'Equity 1',y:35}, { name:'Equity 2',y:21 }, { name:'Equity 3',y:52 }, { name:'Equity 4',y:31}]
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read the documentation. it's pretty clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using this: `xAxis.type: 'category'`

Pseudo code below:

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'category',
},
series: [
    {
      data: [{ name:'Nominal Bonds 1',y:5 }, { name:'Nominal Bonds 2',y:23}]
    },

    {
     data: [{ name:'Inflation 1',y:15 }, { name:'Inflation 2',y:12}, { name:'Inflation 3',y:22}]
    },

    {
    data: [{ name:'Equity 1',y:35}, { name:'Equity 2',y:21 }, { name:'Equity 3',y:52 }, { name:'Equity 4',y:31}]
    }
]
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q97vxzct/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem with this approach is we have to manually assign colors to each data object. I have updated the question to explain how I'm trying to do it.

Comment: Notice that there is a difference between `xAxis.type: 'category'` and between defines array of categories. When you have defined categories your data object shouldn't include name, but the x value to define to which category point belongs. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q97vxzct/

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. Could you please update your answer as well? So that I could mark it as Accepted.